# Why is my container shrinking and leaving white space when i'm reducing the window size

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am new to web dev, I have encountered a problem in my website, my container shrinking and leaving white space when im reducing the window size to make it responsive..

I have tried looking in yt, chatgpt but i cant understand whether it's the padding or is it the margin size that i have given to the divs inside the homepage container.

`HTML CODE`

```
        <section className="homepage-container">
            <section className="homepage-container-line-wrapper">
                <section className="homepage-container-line"></section>
            </section>
            <section className="homepage-container-text">
                    <h1 className="homepage-container-msg">Let's build from here</h1>
                    <h3>The world's leading AI-powered developer platform</h3>
                    <div className="button-wrapper">
                        <input class = "input-github" type="text" placeholder = "Email address " />
                        <button class = "sign-up-github-button">Sign up for Github</button>
                        <button class = "start-enterprise-button">Start a free enterprise trail</button>
                    </div>
                    <p className="homepage-container-promoter-msg">Trusted by the world's leading organization</p>
                    <section class = "homepage-container-link">
                        <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/assets/3m-0151c2fda0ce.svg" alt="" />
                        <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/assets/kpmg-c249f20c5173.svg" alt="" />
                        <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/assets/mercedes-fcf97d2d6ec4.svg" alt="" />
                        <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/assets/sap-96248a56d312.svg" alt="" />
                        <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/assets/pg-f1f19955c4e4.svg" alt="" />
                        <img src="https://github.githubassets.com/assets/telus-df0c2109df99.svg" alt="" />
                    </section>
            </section>
        </section>
```

`CSS CODE`

```
.homepage-container{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url("https://github.githubassets.com/assets/hero-desktop-a38b0fd77b6c.webp");
    background-size : 60%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top 0px right 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display : grid;
    grid-template-columns: 5% 80%;
    background-color : #0d1117;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}

.homepage-container-text{
    display : flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding : 10% 0;    
}

.homepage-container-text-wrapper{
    padding : 0 10%;
}

.homepage-container-text{
    color : white;
    margin: 20% 10%;
    width : 100%;
}
.homepage-container-text input::placeholder{
    padding : 0 10%; 
}
.homepage-container-text input{
    width : 25%;
    border-radius : 5px;
    height : 13%;
    margin : 5% 0;
    border-style : none;
}

.homepage-container-text button{
    display : none;
    width : 80%;
    border-radius : 5px;
    height : 13%;
    margin : 10px 0;
    border-style : none;
}

.button-wrapper{
    max-height : 15%;
}

.input-github{
    height : 100%;
}

.homepage-container-msg{
    font-size: 5rem;
}

.homepage-container-img{
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}

.homepage-container-promoter-msg{
    margin : 4% 0%;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.homepage-container-line-wrapper{
    box-sizing :border-box;
    margin : 5rem 2rem 5rem 2rem;
    width : 100%;
    display : flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height : 75%;
}

.homepage-container-line{
    border-color : white;
    border-width : 0 0 0 3px;
    border-style: solid;
}

.homepage-container-msg{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.homepage-container-link{
    width: 100%;
    display : flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.sign-up-github-button{
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    color : white;
    border-style : none;
    height : 13%;
    border-radius: 5px;    
}

@media (max-width : 905px){
    .homepage-container{
        width : 100%;
    }
}
```

`WHATS HAPPENING`

[image: Picture for reference]

What I tried : Use calc(100% - padding/margin space) box-sizing : border-box

Comment: First of all, please provide a proper [mre] of the issue, when asking this kind of question. What you have shown us so far, does not look like it comes even close to reproducing what your screenshot shows us - https://jsfiddle.net/rLum94an/

Comment: From your screenshot, I would _guess_ that your navigation appears to be too wide, so it expands beyond the viewport? But that will not make the body element itself "wider" as well, so any block level / 100% width content inside it will still stick to the viewport width.

Answer (score -2):

You can try these solution-
1.Adding this css

```
body, html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:"100%",
    height:"100%"
}
```

2.Add this to html code inside head tag.
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Not working tho.

Comment: Are you using any library like reactjs or plain html and css?

Comment: From the image it looks like the page body is consuming the full size of the container already.  Though, it's hard to determine much without the code that generated the page in the screenshot.